# How to create a numpy array from a string containing scientific notation

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, scientific-notation

I have a set of data I want to process from a text file where each line is to be a numpy array. Some are easy to convert to arrays using the fromstring method, but other have scientific notation entries within them. How would I go about converting those into a np array?

My data looks like (this would have to be one array):

```
0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00 8.02796109e-07 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 9.99999197e-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do

`np.array(x.split(), dtype=np.float)`

where x is your string

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
import numpy as np
nn = np.array(['0.00122300e+10', '43434'])
nn = nn.astype(float)
print (nn)
#array([12230000.,    43434.])
```